# Good alternative for GeocodeFarm?

Tags: geocoding, geocode

I've been using GeocodeFarm for several years now, but it's been a struggle lately. The support is very slow and not at all supportive and technical issues they are having started to insfluence the business - for example, to get a result now you sometimes need to query their server 2 to 10 times before you actually get it and there's no ETA on fixing it.

I'm now looking for a good replacement for it. Unfortunately, we cannot use Google Maps as they restrict their usage (even paid-as-you-go one) for commercial projects and i'm not able to pay for permium services as we are not that big.

Are there any reasonably priced and reliable alternative for GeocodeFarm? We are now paying £100/month for 25k requests and are ok with the price

Comment: geocode.xyz ($100 per month no limit cap)

Answer (score 0):

geocode.xyz ($100 per month no limit cap)